# "Protocol error" mounting VirtualBox shared folders in an Ubuntu guest

Tags: mount, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 10 as the guest OS on a Windows 7 machine.  I have been trying to setup shares through VirtualBox, but nothing is working.  First, I create the share in VirtualBox and point it to a Windows folder.  Then I try to mount the drive in Linux, but I keep getting

```
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error
```

I have read so many solutions to this, but none seem to work.  I have tried:

- Using the mount.vboxsf syntax
- Reinstalling VBox additions
- Rebooting
- Enabling and trying as root account

I made a share called "Test" in VBox Shared folders.  Then I made a directory in ubuntu named "test2".  Then I tried to execute this command:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf Test /mnt/test2
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: i tried all the answers and after installing `dkms` error persisted. But the solution to me was to just `restart` ubuntu and mount again. It worked.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In order to use shared folder functionality few [prerequisites](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868) need to be met:

- Make sure that [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtual-box/22745#22745) are properly installed on the guest OS.
- Users in a guest Ubuntu must be in the group `vboxsf` to be able to access shares.
- Define a directory on the host that will be used in the virtual machine using the settings dialogue of Virtual Box.

Depending on host or guest OS the following may also be needed:

- Do not share personal folders like `/home/username` or `My Documents`
- Avoid special characters or empty spaces in the path to the shared folder, especially if the host or VM is a Windows machine
- Use different names for share and mountpoint
- Create a mountpoint on the guest OS (best in your HOME directory).

**Testing** shared folders functionality can be done by creating a shared directory on the host (e.g. `C:\myshare`), define this as a shared folder for your guest system in Virtual Box settings (e.g. `share`), create a mount point in your guest os (e.g.  `mkdir /home/username/host`) and mount this in the guest OS with the command:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 share /home/username/host
```

where the option -o makes sure that you will have access to the mount (that will otherwise be owned by root).

For further information on shared folders see also the [Virtual Box User Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders).

Files or directories can also be shared over the network by using Samba on the host and the guest.

Comment: I believe I have met all of these requirements but am still getting the error.  Is there a way that I can diagnose what the problem is?

Comment: Not to the string literal level, but my share is C:\test instead of C:\myshare, it is defined in VBox 4.0.4.  I have made a folder in /home/[myusername]/test2 and a folder in /mnt/test2 and run the command exactly on these two folders and both return the same error.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't realize that the words "test" and "Test2" would be considered as using the same name.  This solved the problem!

Comment: My problem was with the name apparently. It started after I applied an update. Now solved by changing the mounted name to something other than the actual name.

Comment: everything is good and done. but i need to mount the the shared folder every time I login..ANY ADVICE

Comment: @abh-kirrack: for a permanent solution see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52328/mount-virtualbox-sharedfolder-in-ubuntu-vm-on-boot

Comment: It might be worth noting that `share` should be the shared folder's name defined in the setting dialogue on VirtualBox (I found some trusted answers in other questions suggest to use a full path of the shared folder's on the host).

Comment: For 'share' I'd foolishly used sf_[sharename], since I could see it was being mounted under /media/ with that name and assumed it would need the ubuntu-local name and not VBox's own name.  However, I removed the 'sf_' prefix and this solved the problem.

Comment: To avoid the error, if have to rename the share first before mounting it (via menu item of the guest window). Any ideas why?

Comment: @ChristianSchulzendorff: hard to say generally - it may be a name conflict from sharename and mountpoint

Comment: 1 upvote for adding `uid` and `gid`. This solved it for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'Do not share personal folders like /home/username or My Documents'? Is that your own (quite reasonable) advice, or an actual restriction? If it's a restriction, how does VirtualBox determine blacklisted directories? Does it just reject `$HOME`, or is this a setting somewhere?

Comment: Also, please define 'special characters'. I don't believe Linux restricts characters in filenames at all (you can even include a slash in a filename by escaping it out), so is this a real restriction when the host and guest are both Linux boxen? [Citation needed]

Comment: @MichaelScheper these are recommendations **only** - if it works for you, all is fine.

Comment: I tried to edit the answer to make it clear they're just your recommendations, but it seems the reviewer didn't understand that those points aren't actually 'needed' for it to work, but rather your own (quite reasonable) recommendations. Oh well.

Comment: @MichaelScheper: I did not make up these recommendations, they are not "mine" and I prefer to not claim they are. Unfortunately your edit made this wrong impression.

Comment: Okay, fair enough; I misunderstood your previous comment—mea culpa. But then, I suggest you expand on the recommendations, or cite their source. I just did some websearching about sharing home directories in VirtualBox, and while I see well founded concerns about security, and about different versions of applications working on the same data, I haven't found anything suggesting it could cause this error. My concern is that readers may waste time 'fixing' things that have nothing to do with the error in the question, and that it may be incorrect to say they 'depend on the host or guest OS'.

Comment: @MichaelScheper: as always I did give a reference to my source in the answer, you may not have seen it. In the troubleshoot guide (click link on prerequisites) from the **official** Virtual Box forum it is stated: *You're sharing a personal folder like your Home Folder (Linux), or My Documents (Windows) on the Host.* - I am sorry for the time you had wasted, did you manage to get it working in the meantime? The last sentence of my answer  actually is my own recommendation: use a network share for consistent results through all VMs - at least that is how I share my documents.

Comment: Hi. Sorry to drag this out; you clearly are open to the point I've been trying to make, and I appreciate it. I actually did follow that link, and while it does say the short notation for the home folder is not allowed (`~` in POSIX), and it suggests sharing a subdirectory of My Documents _as a troubleshooting exercise_, I don't see where it says those directories can't be shared at all. I actually have shared home folders myself, e.g. /home/myuser, without issue. I did solve my issue (embarrassingly https://askubuntu.com/a/1063266/135088); I just question this is the best answer for others.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the same name for share and mountpoint, that was the problem. But is is weird, I don't understand why we cannot use the same name... By the way, it worked for me in read-only mode even if my user was not in a vboxsf group.

Answer (score 17):

I also met this trouble. I found that the shared folder were already mounted at `/media/sf_share`.

I tried to delete `/media/sf_share`, but I couldn't.

So I deleted shared folder "share" in my home directory.

```
$ rm -r ~/share
```

And then switch to root user with the following way:

```
$ sudo -i
```

Create softlink/shortcut to the /media/sf_share folder that owns by root user modify the ownership of softlink with chown command. Exit from root user to normal user

```
# ln -s /media/sf_share /home/username/share
# chown username.username /home/username/share
# exit
logout

$ chmod 777 ~/share
```

You can see the files in Windows through the shared folder.
And username must be a member of group vboxsf.

Comment: Thanks ! you were right... already mounted in /media/sf_sharename

Comment: Using CentOS 7, and I also found that my directory is mounted at `media/sf_sharename`.  Creating a symlink to that directory would seem to be a possible option, but this is quite different from the advertised/documented procedure on the VirtualBox site.  There must be a proper resolution to this!?!?

Answer (score 12):

**Here is what worked for me without any problem**

I figured it out that, actually my `user` name was not in **vboxsf** group. Following two commands will help to get the group info:

```
grep "vboxsf" /etc/group    
grep "saurav" /etc/group
```

So I added `saurav` (me) to the **vboxsf** group using following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf saurav
```

Then restarted the virtualbox and then.. Jumped from my placed.. :D :D Everything worked fine without any problem.

Please comment if any one still having any problem..

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. There is only a type: should be `sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf saurav` (first group then user).

Comment: Yes.. Typed incorrect.. :) Thanks for pointing out. Edited now..

Comment: You don't need to restart VB to acquire your newly assigned group.   
 

    $ su - saurav

will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled a lot with the mounting, and tried everything I come up with in the interwebz but I finally found a very weird workaround to solve it! My guest is Ubuntu 13 and my host is Windows 7.

Change to the media folder and from there type `user@os:/media$ sudo mount -t vboxsf share /home/username/folder`

Yeah, that's it. But I don't understand how come it only works if it's done from the media folder. If someone knows please kindly explain us below. Thanks.

P.s. Editing my `/etc/rc.local` to do the automounting at startup doesn't work for me.

Comment: /etc/rc.local will never work, since it's done before the network is up.

Comment: Hi Braiam! Nice to know. Unfortunately I have read in countless of sites people recommend editing the /etc/rc.local for the automounting. Do you know what is the correct way to automount it on startup? Thanks.

Comment: I am also finding it only works from /media. Very strange. I just added this to my .profile: `pushd media && sudo mount /media/<theshare> && popd`.

Answer (score 2):

Tried all the aforesaid and nothing worked for me. 
Lastly I created a new transient folder "Shared" with "Make Permanent" and "Auto Mount" enabled. And then I run the command

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 Shared /mnt/sharedvm
```

It worked for me. No error this time.

Answer (score 1):

With VirtualBox 5.1.20 running on Windows 10, and Ubuntu 16.04 as the guest OS with GuestAdditions 5.1.20 installed, I couldn't mount the shared folders from the command line. The mount commands failed, with mentions of Protocol Error and sf_read_super_aux err=-22.

Eventually I found https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16670 "mount.vboxsf symlink broken". I followed one of the workarounds there, to correct the symlink for mount.vboxsf, and it all worked. My approach was to do:

```
mv /sbin/mount.vboxsf /sbin/mount.vboxsf-orig
ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.1.20/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf /sbin/mount.vboxsf
```

The commands need to be done by root. So, because it was Ubuntu, I added "sudo " at the beginning of each line to do the command as root. Other flavors of Linux have other ways of doing that.

As an aside, there was a similar symlink problem reported in virtualbox's Ticket #12879 "Can't mount shared folders with guest additions 4.3.10" in 2014, that was fixed the following month.

2017-04-27

Comment: @duncan: good point. The title of the ticket describes the problem, but I edited to show the solution I used.

Comment: The changelog for virtual box v5.1.22 at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog#v22 says that

Comment: The changelog for virtual box v5.1.22, released 2017-04-28, (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog#v22), says that this bug/ticket #16670 is fixed. I'm excited!

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but it helped me with my problems using Vbox 5.122

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that I was a goose, and I'd forgotten that I'd removed the entry from my Shared Folders list in VirtualBox (Machine→Settings→Shared Folders).

I'm just throwing this in here, in case anybody else is ever similarly mislead by 'Protocol error'.

*:honk:*

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few answers and then saw [void's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest/1248860#comment2063604_30396) saying he restarted the Linux guest OS and re-mounted.

Worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

My shared folder was working and after rebooting my host, it wasn't.

By changing the name of the shared folder from Shared to Shared2 it worked.

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/username/Dropbox/Shared", "/Shared2"
```

No idea on what happened and why nor how to fix.
System with no global mutable state like Nix do have a point.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I faced the same error message and the problem was related to the fact I did a typo related to the folder located on the host machine and which I set as a shared folder from within the virtual machine thanks to the guest additions.

So the right command is:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) shared_folder_located_in_host_machine path_to_mounting_folder_inside_the_virtual_machine
```

This fixed the error message.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the wrong version of guest-additions.

I moved my whole VM from one laptop (which ran VirtualBox 5.8/something) to another laptop with VirtualBox 6.0. Everything worked except the mounting of shared folder.

I just started VM, clicked on `Devices -> Insert Guest additions CD image...` and followed instructions. It cribbed a bit about presence of older version of guest additions, but then removed it and installed the new one on second attempt. Reboot and works.