# What is the easiest method to share files between Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, windows-7, file-sharing

I have a Windows 7 installed on my laptop. I installed VirtualBox 4.1.4 with Ubuntu 11.10.

Now I want to be able to copy files from Windows to Ubuntu and vice versa.

What is the easiest method to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing files from Windows with Ubuntu as a guest OS can be done via *["Shared Folders"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest/30446#30446)* that can be mounted or [auto-mounted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52328/mount-virtualbox-sharedfolder-in-ubuntu-vm-on-boot/52366#52366) in the guest OS.

Alternatively, we can also setup a network share via [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide).

Comment: The "Shared Folders" method worked like a magic! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/). There are Ubuntu (installed by default) and [Windows](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/) clients available, so you can sync files between them easily with an Internet connection.

I use this to keep both my Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 partitions on my laptop in sync with each other and my 11.10 desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Do this thing
1.After installing the virtual box you can setup the shared folder which will be available for your windows 7 host as a normal folder but for ubuntu11.10 it will be mounted at **/media/sf_name_of_your_shared_folder**.

2.This folder will be accessible only through the root account(to open it type **sudo nautilus /media/** and then open it from ubuntu.