# connecting ubuntu with 7 via network cable

Tags: networking, file-sharing, sharing

i was tryin to connect my ubuntu toshiba satalite L650 laptop with my desktop via a network cable so that i can share things and remotely control the desktop from the laptop, i googled the problem out and found a guide page , i followed all the steps , i installed samba, i had the two computer have the same workgroup name , i had everything correct, but i still dont see connection estbalished between the two computers, 
(neither one is visible to the other)
what is missing ?
thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you connecting the 2 computers directly with a single cable or through a switch/router?

Comment: directly (single cable)

Comment: Is this a cross-link (crossover) cable? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Comment: i think its a RJ45 cable (its blue)

Comment: See my answer on crossover cable or an alternative solution with using a switch.

Comment: Did you see the lights in both LAN adapter is blinking/ steady?
One will be green another will be orange. If not connectivity is not established. Check  the cable and lan ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link will help u go through these references :

[What is the easiest method to share files between Windows and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76403/what-is-the-easiest-method-to-share-files-between-windows-and-ubuntu)

[How to setup a LAN between Ubuntu and Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-setup-a-lan-between-ubuntu-and-windows)

[Sharing Internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58161/connect-ubuntu-to-other-pc-with-direct-crossover-cable)

Comment: directly with a single cable

Comment: @Vexe is this answer is helpful 2 u or your problem get slove

Answer (score 1):

You need a [crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) to connect 2 machines directly (without a router/switch/hub).

Crossover cables are usually marked with a label and/or have red connectors, but it is not a standard. The best way to determine is to *compare the wiring colours* at the connectors. If they seem to match it is a *straight through cable*.

[image: Crossover cable]

[*Crossover cable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vergleich_2von2_Crossoverkabel.jpg)

Alternatively you can use a switch/hub/router and another cable to connect the machines into a network. In this case you'll need 2 normal cables and a eg. switch:

```
[ Machine 1 ]-----[ Switch ]-----[ Machine 2 ]
```

Comment: Modern ethernet cables don't require to be crossover cable for connecting two same type of device.

Comment: @Web-E To be exact it is „modern interfaces” (the cables are basically the same). But anyway true if the LAN ports in the machines do support Auto-MDIX. Switches usually have this feature, so they are not sensitive to cable wiring. I'd suggest to either try to use a CO cable or connect through a switch to see if it makes any difference.