# Windows computers cannot see my Ubuntu machine?

Tags: 12.04, networking, windows

Well I have a Windows machine and also a Ubuntu laptop, my Ubuntu laptop can see everything in the network, but Windows cannot see Ubuntu. Please remember that I am an absolute beginner to Networking and Ubuntu, so keep it simple!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may wan to see this question: [Setup a LAN](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-setup-a-lan-between-ubuntu-and-windows?lq=1) & [Share Files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76403/what-is-the-easiest-method-to-share-files-between-windows-and-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Windows does not(I don't want to use the incorrect technical terminology) recognize the format of the Linux OS, but Linux did program their OS to recognize Windows(ntfs). However you could write a text document with a Linux text application, and Windows would be able to open it with Notepad. For the most part you can
open, not everything, but Linux is way more flexible toward Windows. I hope that helps.

Comment: This applies to (1) accessing files on a partition belonging to another operating system installed on the same machine and (2) opening files that were created in a different operating system. But the question here is about accessing files *on a different machine, over a network*.