# VirtualBox 4.3.22 with Windows 8.1 x64 sharing folder

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-8

I'm trying to install Windows 8.1 x64 in a virtual machine.

The problem is that I can enable the function to share a folder between host and guest.

I followed the steps in this link: http://www.itworld.com/article/2696611/open-source-tools/install-virtualbox-4-3-14-in-ubuntu-14-04.html

I created a folder to share in /home/"my name"/ and when logged in the guest, I installed the guest addition that came in "CD Drive (D:) VirtualBox Guest Additions" under Devices and drives (The amd64 version).

When I click on "map network drive" and then browse to open the folder I'd like to share, it doesn't appear. It appears 2 networks: My name, and VBOXSVR. Under my name, the folders are the ones that come by default (Music, photos, etc.), and under VBOXSVR it appears nothing.

I don't know if I missed something, or if I had to write something in the terminal after creating the folder to share.

If someone could help, even give the step by step from installing the virtualbox under Ubuntu 14.04 to sharing folder when installed the Windows drive, I would really appreciate.

Comment: Does https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders help?

Comment: I believe you will answer from this earlier post, http://askubuntu.com/questions/103069/shared-folder-in-virtualbox-ubuntu-and-windows-7?rq=1

Comment: After typing in the terminal `sudo usermod -g vboxsf username`, I got this message: `usermod: group 'vboxsf' does not exist`

Comment: In VirtualBox's **Shared Folders** dialog box for this Windows VM, which folders have you chosen to share?

Comment: /home/my name/VBoxShare

Comment: If you open windows explorer and type in the top bar `\\VBOXSVR\VBoxShare`, do you get an error?

Comment: you should be able to share using apache or samba across the network

Answer (score 0):

The shared folder problems with Windows guests are [a known bug](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=312593#p312593), which can be fixed by downloading and installing [VirtualBox Guest Additions 4.3.23 r98282](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.23-98282.iso).