# Permission issue between Windows 10 host and Ubuntu 19.04 usiing VirtualBox

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, windows-10

I have shared my Windows 10 home folder as a host in VirtualBox with my Ubuntu 19.04 guest OS. However, I cannot drill down into the Documents folder, because Ubuntu claims it does not have permission.

How do I grant permission for Ubuntu to drill down into all of these folders?

Comment: Seems like a Windows/Virtualbox (host) permissions issue, which does not have anything to do with Ubuntu (guest). You might try Virtualbox's excellent help forums.

Comment: Try installing [Guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/a/784355/78223).