# File sharing from GUEST VirtualBox ( 12.04 ) to HOST ( 10.04 )

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, virtualbox, file-sharing

I've completed 90% of this walkthrough:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders#Getting_VBoxLinuxAdditions.iso

... and I'm currently in the " Prepare Guest " section. Where this is giving me problems:

> sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 $sharename /mnt/$sharename \

the " -t " option is giving me issues as per this error message when running the full set of commands:

> mkdir invalid option --t
>
> Try ' mkdir --help ' for more information.

So! If I've already configured the share on the host ... and I'm attempting to mount a local dir on the GUEST system for the HOST to view

... What should I be doing differently here?

Comment: Where does the command `mkdir` come in? For shared folders see these questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest/30446#30446 http://askubuntu.com/questions/52328/mount-virtualbox-sharedfolder-in-ubuntu-vm-on-boot

Comment: Thats kind of what is weird to me ... clearly something is incorrect with the commands listed on the page ... however I'm not sure what

Comment: Also it seems that this is sharing from the HOST to the GUEST ... I need the HOST to be able to R/W on the GUEST VM

Answer (score 1):

Setting up shared folder can be done from Virtual Box as it was further elaborated in answers to these question:

- [Error mounting VirtualBox shared folders in an Ubuntu guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest)
- [Mount VirtualBox SharedFolder in Ubuntu VM on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52328/mount-virtualbox-sharedfolder-in-ubuntu-vm-on-boot)

However because it is so much easier to set up (and they safer in addition) I usually share folders to and from a virtual machine using basic **network shares** from the Nautilus right click *"Sharing Options"* menu. These can be set up anytime and will immediately be accessible from the *"Browse Network"* entry in Nautilus.

After right click on a directory from your HOME for *Sharing Options* we may be asked to download **samba** packages - do so. Then we tick the *Share this folder* box and give the needed permissions for this share to enable sharing over the network.

[image]

We may have to restart our session for changes to take effect. After having defined our shared directory we can browse it using Nautilus *Browse Network* where our share appears in the `Windows Network/WORKGROUP/` directory.

[image]

Fo ease of use I have set my network adapter to *bridged* in the Virtual Box Manager.

Comment: So I've actually attempted to share via the right click option to no avail.  I've run "gksudo nautilus" and enabled the sharing of the /usr/local/ dir with all permissions ... however I'm unable to open that up via the HOST machine.  It should be accessible from within nautilus under the "Network" icon right?

Comment: For security we should only share directories in our HOME. Sharing system directories e.g. in `/usr/..` may lead to unwanted side effects or may even break your system. See edit for shots.

Comment: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: failed to add share bety. Error was Operation not permitted   .... is the error im getting ... and this is between two ubuntu installations

Comment: You may need to make yourself member of the groups `sambashare` and `shareaccess`.