# Can I copy a machine from VirtualBox so that I can use it on another machine?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to format my laptop and I'm wondering if i can copy a virtual machine (Windows 7), so I do not have to recreate it after formatting.

In VMware I just have to copy the file of the machine and run it everywhere I want. Can I do the same with VirtualBox?

Comment: see my answer to the following: http://askubuntu.com/questions/287867/how-do-i-copy-to-dvd-my-virtualbox-windows-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options

1. Use the **Import/Export** utility
2. Copy the entire VM folder, containing the `.vdi` and `.vbox` files
3. Clone the VDI using **Virtual Media Manager** and then recreate a VM on the target machine but using the cloned VDI as the hard disk.

The first option is the easiest because it combines the whole VM into a single file and transfers it over without issue pretty much every time.

To do that, just click on **File => Export Appliance**  you will get a dialog-box like this

[image: Export dialog]

And then, follow the steps on the screen.

Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have the "export" function on VirtualBox.

File > Export Virtual Machine

Hope this help.