# Backup Virtualbox Windows 7

Tags: virtualbox, backup

I'm experiencing some problems with my current installation of Ubuntu 13.04.  Is there a way to back up my current Virtualbox Windows 7 VM so when I cleanly install Ubuntu again I can just import the VM into Virtualbox without having to reinstall it and all of its software?

Thanks!

Comment: also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/287867/how-do-i-copy-to-dvd-my-virtualbox-windows-data

Answer (score 1):

I've used 2 methods.

1. In the file menu you can export the VM and put it on some other media to use in VB.
2. You can copy the ~/.VirtualBox and the folder where you've saved the VB disk images to   other media and then copy them back after your re-install  (Like this personal)

Answer (score 0):

Or just copy the virtual disk file (.vdi or whatever) that is in the virtual machine's folder.