# Auto Mount in Virtual Box and Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox

How is it possible to auto mount in Virtual Box using Linux 13:04? 
I tried to put in fstab and rc.local

```
Project/mnt/Project vboxsf umask=002,gid=1000,uid=1000
```

but did not work

Can anyone help me? When I put these files get an error on startup saying

> "Unable to mount / mnt / Project"

Thanks.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup and http://askubuntu.com/questions/52328/mount-virtualbox-sharedfolder-in-ubuntu-vm-on-boot. In the line above a blank is missing. It should be `Project /mnt/Project`. It may only be a typo then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 4.0, `VirtualBox` can mount shared folders automatically, at your option. If automatic mounting is enabled for a specific shared folder, the Guest Additions will automatically mount that folder as soon as a user logs into the guest OS.

So you first have to install the guest addition in your VM.

**Note:**

> Access to auto-mounted shared folders is only granted to the user
>   group **vboxsf**, which is created by the VirtualBox Guest Additions
>   installer. Hence guest users have to be member of that group to have
>   read/write access or to have read-only access in case the folder is
>   not mapped writable.

Ensure that the targeted users have been made member of the group **vboxsf**.

Source: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto