# How to navigate to Windows 7 shared folders from Ubuntu guest with terminal?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, shared-folders, virtualbox-networking

I'm running a VirtualBox with Ubuntu 64-bit, configured as a Bitnami Djangostack. I'm running this within a Windows 7 64-bit host.

Though my VirtualBox is what runs the server, I'd like my website files to be hosted on my main machine (Windows 7) for easier editing.

I set up Virtualbox to share the specific Windows 7 folder with my Ubuntu guest. It is set to automatically mount.

Now, I'd like to navigate to that folder from my Ubuntu terminal (no GUI installed).  How should I do that ?

Comment: `cd /path/to/folder`

Comment: Right, but what is the path to a network shared folder ?

Comment: Did you used Virtualbox share directories or how exactly are you sharing?

Comment: From your comment below we can see that you shared folder is not mounted. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest on how to do that. Or consider a Samba network share instead.

Answer (score 0):

try using command `mount` to check which folder to navigate to and then `cd /path/to/mounted/point`

**EDIT:**
@Takkat is right if you don't have your folder properly mounted you won't see it after typing `mount` - so give it a try, dwell a bit SE and get it right; good luck!
btw - sorry for getting answer on this but considering my rep I cannot comment on questions.

Comment: I get [this](http://cynicalgames.com/mount.png) when using "mount".