# How to share files from Host to Guest in VirtualBox? Host-Ubuntu, Guest-Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 machine on which I have installed VirtualBox with Ubuntu 12.04 as the guest OS.

How can I share files between the host and guest?

I have installed the guest additions also but still it’s not able to mount the sf_shared folders if even it’s mounted. This means I'm unable to retrieve the file from the host.

Comment: also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest - but I recommend to use Ubuntu's inbuilt file sharing through the virtual network.

Comment: @EricCarvalho It does seem like one of these should be made a duplicate of the other. The titles can be edited if necessary, since there aren't that many differences between Ubuntu and other *hosts* for this. Either way, answers of the closed questions can be merged into the other, especially if there's concern about them being obscured or (less likely) someday deleted. This one has far more views, but for most people I suspect the answer on the other one might be the most valuable.

Answer (score 45):

I do not believe its possible to share files between the host and the guest without installing the extension pack first though I could be wrong on this.

You can find that here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Check that the version of Virtualbox you have. Mine is 4.2.18 and double click the link

You should see something like this

[image]

Click OK and let it install.

Next step create a folder on your host machine as as share area

I've created one called `VboxShare` in my home directory.

[image]

First, make sure that your virtual machine is powered off.

[image: machine-state-powered-off-image]

Then, go into settings for your virtual machine, select shared folders then the plus icon to create a shared folder and fill in the details set it to auto mount.

[image]

Click OK then start your guest.

Job Done the shared folder appears on you guest machine as

```
/media/sf_Vboxshare
```

[image]

There is only one more step add any user in your guest system that needs access to the folder to the group **vboxsf**:

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxsf
```

Log out and back in, everything should work fine now.

Comment: @Richard: can you explain your comment? Are you saying `sudo adduser $USER vboxsf` doesn't work or that `sudo useradd -g $USER vboxsf` is somehow preferable?

Comment: This last command to adduser, is that done on the host machine or on the guest machine?  Looks like it should be done on the guest machine because $USER means someone else on the host machine, but just checking.  All my commands succeed but I still don't see anything in the shared folder on the guest machine.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin it says in the answer this is on the guest machine you also need to log out and back in again on the guest machine.

Comment: @WarrenHill that did it, tyvm.

Answer (score 10):

On the VM settings in the *Shared folders* section, remember the name of your shared forlder!
After installing the *VBox Guest additions* on the guest OS fire up a terminal and type in

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf <share-name> /where/to/share
```

may wanna check https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15868

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Devices` option of your VM and click on the `Shared Folders` option and add the `required_folder` you want to share.
Now in your file system (root) you can see `media/sf_required_folder`.
But by default the Guest User won't have access to this folder. So to grant access to this folder you need to add Guest user to the group `vboxsf`.
For this, `sudo adduser Guest_user vboxsf` to give access. Now have the access.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to share files and folders you can use Vbox extensions as mentioned in other posts.

*Alternatively*  you can use **Nitroshare** :

1. Install *Nitroshare*  (in **host** and in **guest** )

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nitroshare
   ```

   There are four ways to install *Nitroshare* - reference : [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678166/how-to-install-latest-version-of-nitroshare-on-ubuntu)
2. Start *Nitroshare* (in **guest** and **host**) from the dash or from a terminal command `nitroshare`

   You will see the tray icon on top right corner :

   [image: Imgur]
3. By default the destination folder is `~/Desktop`. You can modify it in **settings**.

   [image: Imgur]
4. Sending **files and folders**:

   Select _send files/Directory _ from the tray icon, select the file /directory you want to share, click on  <kbd>open</kbd>.

   Then select the VM device from the menu and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

   [image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

Try this combo. I used this as I am using AMD64 CPU.

```
virtualbox-4.3_4.3.6-91406~Ubuntu~precise_amd64 with extenstion pack -
Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.6-91406
```

It works. Also Make sure

After installing the VBox Guest additions on the guest OS (VM) fire up a terminal on Guest server and type in

```
mount -t vboxsf  /shared-name /where/to/share
```

Example

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf /home/myshare /mnt
```

where `/home/myshare` is a folder on Host Server and `/mnt` is a folder on guest server.

Start dumping files on host folder `/home/myshare` and see the same on guest `/mnt`