# Running in a VM. How can I access the host computer's files?

Tags: files, sharing

I'm running Ubuntu in a VM, which is running on a Win7 host.  How can I access the host computer's files?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/q/366742/202806

Answer (score 2):

The exact steps will vary depending on what VM solution you are using, but the general concept is usually the same. Typically a hidden virtual network is used to enable shared network folder or drive.

## How to enable a shared folder in VMware Player:

[Windows 8 - Core X86-64 host][Ubuntu 12.04 - Desktop X86-64 guest]

[image: Step #1]

[image: Step #2]

[image: Step #3]

[image: Step #4]

[image: Step #5]

[image: Step #6]

[image: Step #7]

[image: Step #8]

[image: Step #9]

[image: Step #10]

## How to enable a shared folder in Virtual Box:

[Windows 8 - Core X86-64 host][Ubuntu 12.04 - Desktop X86-64 guest]

[Guest Addons must be installed, or the folder won't show up in the guest.]

[image: Step #1]

[image: Step #2]

[image: Step #3]

[image: Step #4]

[image: Step #5]

[image: Step #6]

[image: Step #7]

[image: Step #8]

**Additional Information:**

## How to install vmware tools on Ubuntu guest:

[vmware tools are for vmware obviously]

Step #1 = https://copy.com/8rA1r3VM4iNr/screen_shot_install_vmware_tools_on_ubuntu_guest_1.png

Step #2 = copy.com/GY7LId3Gmbe3/screen_shot_install_vmware_tools_on_ubuntu_guest_2.PNG

Step #3 = copy.com/ZkuU9zwlL7oI/screen_shot_install_vmware_tools_on_ubuntu_guest_3.PNG

Step #4 = copy.com/i7qTUkENFVge/screen_shot_install_vmware_tools_on_ubuntu_guest_4.PNG

Step #5 = copy.com/ckO09RNaECfB/screen_shot_install_vmware_tools_on_ubuntu_guest_5.PNG

Step #6 = copy.com/iEOZTz4Y0gsp/screen_shot_install_vmware_tools_on_ubuntu_guest_6.PNG

Step #7 = copy.com/dThBlFl1gruT/screen_shot_install_vmware_tools_on_ubuntu_guest_7.PNG

## How to install guest addons on Ubuntu guest:

[guest addons are for virtualbox]

Step #1 = https://copy.com/gCACBiKIrO8j/screen_shot_install_guest_addons_on_ubuntu_guest_1.png

Step #2 = copy.com/P0kVyO9TGr2r/screen_shot_install_guest_addons_on_ubuntu_guest_2.PNG

Step #3 = copy.com/K0BWcXnRkZDJ/screen_shot_install_guest_addons_on_ubuntu_guest_3.PNG

Comment: The image is viewable on the link page no download is required.

Comment: Oops, Sorry. Will fix now.

Answer (score 1):

what about sharing a directory on Win VM and reach it via smb?

If your PCs (physical and vitual one) are on the same network (and I can't see why not), you just have to share a directory on windows and reach it from linux via samba, writing:

```
smb://WindowsIPAddress/share
```

in your file manager (nautilus or whatever you use).

Vice versa, you can share a directory on your linux machine and reach it from windows via "map network drive".

Cheers,

Silvia