# Transfer files from virtualbox ubuntu server /var/www to local ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualbox

I have a Ubuntu `virtualbox` installed Ubuntu Server. My local machine has Ubuntu 12.04 OS. I need to copy files from the /var/www in the `virtualbox` Ubuntu Server in to my local machine. (My network settings in `virtualbox` is "Bridged Adapter" and it has a static IP: 192.168.56.101)
My local mchine IP is : 192.168.56.1

I tried following

```
scp -r test.php nilani@192.168.56.1:
```

It says

```
Port 22: No route to host
lost connection.
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you just [share some folder](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-shared-folder-in-virtual-box) from host Ubuntu?

Comment: @c0rp: I have lot of files in /var/www folder which I need to copy to my local machine?

Comment: It is not a problem, and it would be faster then copy through ssh.

Comment: @c0rp: How can I share /var/www directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that you have `openssh-server` installed on your local machine, if not:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then from your Virtual Machine:

```
scp /var/www/test.php nilani@192.168.56.1:/home/nilani
```

Alternatively you could do the other way around, this time from your local machine:

```
scp your_server_login@192.168.56.101:/var/www/test.php .
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote my answer please. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can share some folder on your `host` machine. Host machine is your "real" Ubuntu where VirtualBox is installed.

For example:

Create folder in your $HOME

```
mkdir $HOME/vbox_share
```

Now using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366742/how-to-share-the-files-from-host-to-guest-in-virtual-box-host-ubunutu-guest-ubu) share this folder to virtual machine. Don't forget to check `automount` option, and name it `vbox_share`

After that you should see this folder on your virtual Ubuntu in the `/media/vbox_share`

---

**Update**

I forgot to say. If you will do this while your virtual Ubuntu is powered on, you should mount shared folder manually:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf vbox_share /media/vbox_share
```

---

Now just copy `/var/www`

```
mkdir -p /media/vbox_share/var/www
cp -R /var/www /media/vbox_share/var/www
```

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage I update answer a little bit. You are welcome!