# Mounting issue with Mac-host and Ubuntu-guest shared folder on VirtualBox

Tags: mount, virtualbox

Using VirtualBox 4.3.28 r100309 on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.3, I have a running ubuntu 14.04 LTS guest machine.  On the mac in virtualbox "Manager" main screen, I right-click the running machine icon, choose "Settings", then choose "Shared Folders" icon on the upper right. Show "Machine Folders" named "mysharedfolder" and path "/Users/joeblogs-user-on-mac/aSharedFolder", auto-mount "Yes", Access "Full".  Now on the guest machine, I do

```
$ sudo adduser joeblogs vboxsf
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf mysharedfolder ~joeblogs/heyThisIsReallyOnTheMac
```

after creating the folder "heyThisIsReallyOnTheMac" in joeblogs's home folder while logged in as joeblogs on the Ubuntu guest.

All click-interactions seem to succeed, and all commands seem to succeed (no error messages), but nothing is in that folder on Ubuntu (of course, there is stuff in the corresponding folder on the mac).  I can find the stuff in /media/sf_mysharedfolder on Ubuntu-guest, but I must be logged in as su, and that's not really great.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer over here: [How to share the files from Host to Guest in virtual box? Host-ubunutu/Guest-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366742/how-to-share-the-files-from-host-to-guest-in-virtual-box-host-ubunutu-guest-ubu/366821?noredirect=1#comment915282_366821).  I had omitted to log out and log back in again.  Doing so made the files show up in the right place.