# How to install latest version of Nitroshare on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, nitroshare

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. How to install and configure the latest version of [NitroShare](https://launchpad.net/nitroshare) on Ubuntu.

I would like to know how to install it from PPA and from source.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are five ways to install NitroShare on Ubuntu:

---

#### Use the Archives (16.04+)

You can install the [nitroshare [image: Install nitroshare]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nitroshare) package directly from the universe repository by executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install nitroshare
```

#### Use the Stable PPA (recommended for older releases)

The stable PPA contains all of the packages necessary to run NitroShare and is considered stable enough for everyday use:

[ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/nitroshare) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

To add this PPA to your computer and install NitroShare, open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nitroshare
```

---

#### Use the Development PPA (unstable)

The development PPA contains daily builds of the packages that comprise NitroShare. Some of the features may be broken or incomplete. For this reason, its use is discouraged for any purpose other than testing or debugging:

[ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare-dev [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/nitroshare-dev) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

The commands for installing NitroShare from the development PPA are similar to the ones for the stable PPA.

---

#### Use the Binary Packages

Binary packages (DEBs) are provided for Ubuntu 14.04+. They can be downloaded from the official NitroShare website:

http://nitroshare.net

Once the DEB package is downloaded, you can launch it to open the Software Center to complete the installation.

---

#### Build NitroShare from Source (difficult)

If you are really ambitious, you can build NitroShare directly from source. First, you will need to ensure that all of the packages needed for building NitroShare are installed. To do that, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default libqt5svg5-dev libgtk2.0-dev \
  libappindicator-dev libnotify-dev
```

Visit [this page](https://launchpad.net/nitroshare/+download) and grab the `.tar.gz` download for the latest release (0.3.0 at the time of writing). Then run the following commands to build everything:

```
tar xf nitroshare-0.3.0.tar.gz
cd nitroshare-0.3.0
qmake
make
```

To install the application, run the following command:

```
sudo make install
```

You will then be able to run NitroShare using the `nitroshare` command.