# How to remove Nitroshare from Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: uninstall, 15.10, nitroshare

I would like to uninstall Nitroshare from ubuntu 15.10. But after installation the program does not show up as installed program in the software center.

How to uninstall Nitroshare?

Comment: Can you start it from terminal, in that case just do a sudo apt-get --purge remove nitroshare

Comment: how you installed nitroshare ? wrt  [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678166/how-to-install-latest-version-of-nitroshare-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

If you installed NitroShare via PPA or by installing one of the binary packages from the website, you can remove it using the following terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get remove nitroshare
```

If you built NitroShare from source, you will need to manually remove the files. Here's a list of the files to remove (`$PREFIX` is usually `/usr` or `/usr/local`):

```
$PREFIX/bin/nitroshare
$PREFIX/share/applications/nitroshare.desktop
$PREFIX/share/icons/gnome/24x24/apps/nitroshare-indicator.png
$PREFIX/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/nitroshare.svg
$PREFIX/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/nitroshare-indicator.svg
$PREFIX/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/22/nitroshare-indicator.png
$PREFIX/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/24/nitroshare-indicator.svg
$PREFIX/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/22/nitroshare-indicator.png
$PREFIX/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/24/nitroshare-indicator.svg
```