# Install Nitroshare on Lubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, lts, nitroshare

I have tried to install Nitroshare on Lubuntu 20.04 LTS using ([How to install latest version of Nitroshare on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678166/how-to-install-latest-version-of-nitroshare-on-ubuntu#678174)) but it does not work. How do I install Nitroshare to my Lubuntu 20.04 LTS?
If this is not possible, what (cross platform) alternatives will install on Lubuntu 20.04 LTS please. I need it for Linux and Windows.

Comment: That link goes to a 5 year old piece of info aimed at 16.04. Are you sure it runs on your version?

Comment: "Is it even possible to install it on Lubuntu?" Yes it is. Now for the annoying part: you are asking for a yes or no. Please edit so you are asking for a problem you face  The creator of it is a regular here: https://askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman

Comment: No David it does not run on my version.