# Getting Guset-Host file sharing to work under ubuntu 16.04 virtualbox 5.1

Tags: virtualbox

As cited in the title I have ubuntu 16.04 and virtualbox 5.1 with the vb extension pack.

I've tried everything in both :

- [How to share the files from Host to Guest in virtual box? Host-ubunutu/Guest-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366742/how-to-share-the-files-from-host-to-guest-in-virtual-box-host-ubunutu-guest-ubu)
- [Sharing between Host and Guest in Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81757/sharing-between-host-and-guest-in-virtualbox/81816#81816)

but shared folder fiercely combats functioning.

I'd like a step by step guide to getting it to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you see this: http://askubuntu.com/a/30446/3940?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` destroys virtualbox installation so that doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry to hear, but you must have the [guest additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) installed to your **guest** OS first for shared folder functionality.