# VBox: Error mounting shared folders in Ubuntu 12.04 guest "gid= requires an argument"

Tags: 12.04, mount, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 guest running on an Ubuntu 13.10 host. I created a shared folder in the host following [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders). When I try to mount the folder in the guest the result is:

```
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$GID shared ~/host
gid= requires an argument (i.e. gid==<arg>)
```

I found no results when searching online for this error.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that unlike `$UID`, `$GID` is not a bash built-in variable. Instead, you may be able to use `$(id -g)` i.e.

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) shared ~/host
```

or (for consistency)

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) shared ~/host
```

Comment: So, is the documentation wrong?