# Folder share in ubuntu as guest on Windows 7

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I have a problem with setting Shared Folders.
Using VirtualBox 4.3.10, with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as gust on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit.

After first attempt I was not able to see shares I set using VirtualBox manager- Settings-Shared folders, as auto mount.

After removing shares using VirtualBox manager I restarted Ubuntu and I noticed folder names the same as removed shares. Folders are not accessible, showing following error:
This location could not be displayed.

You do not have the permission necessary to view the contents of sf_ApolloG.
It seems that it is bogus error since shares are removed.

After setting new share with different name and restarting VirtualBox I can see the share but I am still not able to access it with the same error (above).

======================================

Hello Elder Geek, Takkat and Petronilla Escarabajo.

Thank you very much for your responses.

I think I did not make my post clear enough.

To reiterate:

I am using VirtualBox 4.3.10, with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as guest, on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit (as HOST).

I have all additions installed an I am able to create shared folders.
The problem was that once I have created, I was not able to access share folders. The error message was:

you do not have the permission necessary to view the contents of. . .

So I removed shares.

Later I found a post mentioning that I need to be added to a vboxsf group (as Takkat mentioned), which I did.

Then I have added new shared folders folders and I am able to access them.

The problem is that I still have old (removed) shared folders listed but they are empty. In other words, they are ghost folders.

I did a little experiment and added set of folders as shared, rebooted and removed newly added folders from share.

After rebooting again, all folders I have added in this experiment are still listed as shared.

How do I remove ghosts?

Comment: You are using Windows 7 as host and ubuntu 14.04 as guest? I'm not sure this question relates to 14.04 as much as it does to Windows but you could try reviewing this http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html

Comment: This may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest - most of all make sure your guest user is in group `vboxsf`.

Answer (score 0):

To enable file sharing, you will need to install the latest version of VirtualBox Guest Additions from the following site:

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/

Download the appropriate ISO for the version of VirtualBox you are running and mount it to your Guest OS and install it.

Once you have installed the Guest Additions, you will need to reboot the Guest OS.

Create a share folder on the host OS and set the proper permissions.

Then using VirtualBox Shared Folders in the settings for the guest OS, navigate to the shared folder on the host os.  Ensure that if you are running a firewall program on the host os that you either allow the guest network to connect, or simply disable the firewall temporarily to test the share.