# Unable to mount folder on Ubuntu guest from Windows host (VirtualBox)

Tags: mount, virtualbox

I've got a Windows host machine at work, and want to setup an Ubuntu server to do my web dev work on. I got the server up and running, but I'm trying to mount a shared folder (containing all my site files) from my Windows host to my Ubuntu guest. I've created the shared folder in VB, though my laptop has a "Make Permanent" option my work PC doesn't. I've gone through the steps of installing GuestAdditions. I did check "Auto-mount", and so I do see the folder under `/media/sf_www`, but I'd like to get the folder mounted to `/var/www` instead.

When I go into the Ubuntu box, I follow the instructions from [the Ubuntu help site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders):

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) www /var/www
```

I also tried it with a manual `uid=999,gid=999`, which are the matching vboxadd group and user.

But upon running the mount command, I get a long error:

```
mount: wrongfs type, bad option, badsuperbloc on share, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

It says I can get some useful info in syslog (though that's not a command it looks like?), but I don't see anything there I can find useful.

Any advice? I can always serve out of /media/sf_www, but I'd like to understand why I'm getting the error I'm getting so I can improve, and I'd like to possibly get this working as intended (unless there's a good reason I shouldn't).

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest

Comment: Thanks for the note @Takkat, unfortunately, I had looked over that link previously, but unless I'm not understanding it properly, I wasn't able to get any help from it.