# How to create a shared folder between win8.1 (host) and ubuntu 17.04 in virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox

I am running my win 8.1 as a host operating system and ubuntu 17.04 in oracle VM virtual box as a guest operating system. I want to create a shared folder between this two OS to share and transfer files. I have already created a shared folder using virtual box but I cannot shared files. Please help.

Comment: Are guest additions installed? Are your guest users in group `vboxsf`? Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest