# Ubuntu 16.04 server can't mount vboxsf

Tags: mount, virtualbox, sharing

I have a windows 7 host where I'm using a Virtualbox 5.2.8.
On this Virtualbox I've installed a VM with Ubuntul Server 16.04 and the Guest Additions from this version of virtualbox and I'm trying to share a directory.

Everything is properly set from virtualbox's side, the shared directory it's also present on /media path from ubuntu but unfortunately I can't mount it to be able to see the files from that shared directory (even if it has some files, on ubuntu it's seen as empty).

To mount it, I'm running this command:

```
ben@ubuntu:/mnt$ sudo mount -t vboxsf angfiles shares
```

`/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error`

I already have the /mnt/shares directory.

Can you help me please with a hint to solve this issue?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/30446/3940 - is the guest user in group vboxsf?

Comment: I don't see to have any guest user on my ubuntu guest so I can't add it to a certain group.

Comment: This is the list with my existing users:

root
daemon
bin
sys
sync
games
man
lp
mail
news
uucp
proxy
www-data
backup
list
irc
gnats
nobody
systemd-timesync
systemd-network
systemd-resolve
systemd-bus-proxy
syslog
_apt
lxd
messagebus
uuidd
dnsmasq
ben
vboxadd
sshd

I've just added vboxadd to the vboxsf group and looks to work, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The guest user was vboxadd and after adding it on vboxsf group this issue has been solved.